# Primitive of Cauchy Principal Value?

Tags: distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

I'm trying to solve the following distribution equation for $T$:
$$
xT'=1
$$
I know that the distribution pv$\frac{1}{x}$ satisfies $x$pv$\frac{1}{x}=1$ but i don't really know what to do from there, how do i go about finding the "primitive" of pv$\frac{1}{x}$ to solve for $T$ from this?. Sorry if this is obvious but I'm very new to studying distribution theory so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The primitive of $\operatorname{pv}\frac 1 x$ is $\ln |x|$.

Comment: ... plus a constant, of course.

Comment: So i can just integrate $T'$ like anyother function to get $T$?

Comment: If $T'$ is given by a function, then so is $T$. But for $\operatorname{pv}\frac 1 x$ there is a problem at $x=0.$ On the two open intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ one has $\operatorname{pv}\frac 1 x=\frac 1 x$ so on these intervals $T$ is certainly $\ln |x| + C_\pm,$ where $C_-$ is used on $(-\infty,0)$ and $C_+$ is used on $(0,\infty).$ These constants might differ. But there could also be some term with support only on $\{0\}$.